# Infinite header in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance

I am facing a unique problem (probably apparent by my odd title) which I have been unable to figure out a good (efficient) solution to.

Basically, I have a list which needs to scroll either to the left or right (basically like something you would see in Microsoft Excel or Google Sheets).

Anything to the left will be something like `-A, -B, ..` and anything to the right will continue like `A, B, C, .. , AA, AB, AC, etc.`

[image]

As of now, I am incrementing the `left` style to move the list, however i need some way of adding/removing elements on this list (would continually adding and removing elements degrade performance?)

`I am needing an efficient way of making this infinite.`

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vrff4kfo/)

```js
// Calculate the minimum number of sections
var minSections = document.documentElement.clientWidth / 150; // because each rule is 150px wide

// Initially create our first row
var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("");
for (var index = 0; index < minSections; index++) {
 $("#header").append("<li>" + alphabet[index] + "</li>")
}

document.onkeydown = function myFunction() {
 switch (event.keyCode) {
  case 37:
   document.getElementById("header").style.left = ((parseInt(document.getElementById("header").style.left, 10) || 0) - 10) + "px";
   break;
  case 39:
   document.getElementById("header").style.left = ((parseInt(document.getElementById("header").style.left, 10) || 0) + 10) + "px";
   break;
 }
}


// At this point I am not sure what the best (more efficient) approach to this issue is.
```

```css
html, body {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

.container {
 background: #444;
 padding: 5px 3px;
 overflow: hidden;
 white-space: nowrap;
}

ul {
 position: relative;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
 text-transform: uppercase; 
}

ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 150px;
 text-align:center;
 color: #FFF;
 border-left: 1px solid #FFF;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul li:first-child {
 border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <ul id="header">
 </ul>
</div>
```

**NOTE**: On the above snippet I am emulating a pan with the left and right arrow keys (these will be used to move/scroll the list)

Comment: On what event do you need the header to extend? This is relatively important. I mean, if I understand you correctly, you do not want any type of scroll so they have to be new elements, but they cannot be infinite before they are needed... so there has to be a handler that iterates. Pagination would be my solution to this one, but depends on where you are using it. Having a finite set of elements that fill themselves with "infinite" data. The data of course is finite as you only have what you actually use.

Comment: @Dellirium You are correct and I am sorry for not including that in the question. I plan on people using a mouse to pan around the spreadsheet, however my example makes use of the arrow keys to move the elements.

Comment: Make it with pagination, would be my best bet honestly. If you can structure the data properly, you would have no issues there. Every time your left/right event is triggered, take the array of currently visible elements, remove the first/last data from the DIV, not the div itself, and fill it with the data from your structured data array that holds this info.

Comment: @Dellirium If you look at the screenshot in my question thats something I was thinking about (adding two more elements than I needed so when i pan more than `150px` i prepend (or append) and remove an elements from the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add a prepend/append to your alphabet and `#header` in your `onkeydown` event.

See fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/vrff4kfo/1/

```
// Calculate the minimum number of sections
var ruleWidth = 150; // because each rule is 150px wide
var minSections = Math.ceil(document.documentElement.clientWidth / ruleWidth); 
var leftMost = 0;
var rightMost = minSections;

// Initially create our first row
var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("");
for (var index = 0; index < minSections; index++) {
    $("#header").append("<li>" + alphabet[index] + "</li>")
}

document.onkeydown = function myFunction() {
    var left = parseInt(document.getElementById("header").style.left,10);
    switch (event.keyCode) {
        case 37:
            document.getElementById("header").style.left = ((left || 0) - 10) + "px";
            break;
        case 39:
            document.getElementById("header").style.left = ((left || 0) + 10) + "px";
            break;
    }
  if(left > ruleWidth){
    // Prepend a column
    leftMost++;
    $("#header").prepend("<li>-" + alphabet[leftMost-1] + "</li>");
    document.getElementById("header").style.left= left-ruleWidth + "px";
  }
  if(Math.ceil(minSections + (-left/ruleWidth)) > rightMost){
    //append a column
    rightMost= Math.ceil(minSections + (-left/ruleWidth));
    $("#header").append("<li>" + alphabet[rightMost] + "</li>");
  }
}
```

Once you go past the length of the alphabet in either direction you will of course need to programatically edit the alphabet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what I suggested. So long as you keep the data structured in your java-script, there is no need to add elements and burden the DOM. If you need a table (and I assume you do, you can add a nested loop when filling the data, I've written a comment in the code).

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z62575en/2/)**

**HTML:**

```
<div id="list1" class="item">
</div>
<div id="list2" class="item">
</div>
<div id="list3" class="item">
</div>
<button onclick="moveRight()">
Right
</button>
<button onclick="moveLeft()">
Left
</button>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var structuredData = [
    //These are your columns to add rows under, just add data to their arrays
  //['row1, 'row2', 'row3'] instead of the single row like it is now.
  ["cell1"],
  ["cell2"],
  ["cell3"],
  ["cell4"],
  ["cell5"],
  ["cell6"],
];

var visibleData = {
  list1: {
    element: document.getElementById('list1'),
    dataIndex: 0
  },
  list2: {
    element: document.getElementById('list1'),
    dataIndex: 1
  },
  list3: {
    element: document.getElementById('list1'),
    dataIndex: 2
  },
}

function refreshView() {
  var i;
  for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) { //using 1 intentionally.... coz it corresponds with the ID, loop however u want
    document.getElementById('list' + i).innerHTML = structuredData[visibleData['list' + i].dataIndex][0];
    //The 0 in the last bracket represents a ROW parameter, 
    //which since we are talking header is 0, same like
    //with the structured data array, each array inside is a column,
    //and the elements are row values, if you want to fill out a table,
    //make another loop within this one and circle through rows.
  }
}

refreshView();

function moveRight() {
  var i;
  for (i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
    visibleData['list' + i].dataIndex = visibleData['list' + (i+1)].dataIndex;
  }
  visibleData['list3'].dataIndex = visibleData['list2'].dataIndex + 1;
  if (!structuredData[visibleData['list3'].dataIndex]){
    //newColumn needs to be added to the right
    structuredData[visibleData['list3'].dataIndex] = ["cellNewAfter"];
  }
  refreshView();
}

function moveLeft() {
  var i;
  for (i = 3; i > 1; i--) {
    visibleData['list' + i].dataIndex = visibleData['list' + (i-1)].dataIndex;
  }
  visibleData['list1'].dataIndex = visibleData['list2'].dataIndex - 1;
  if (!structuredData[visibleData['list1'].dataIndex]){
    //newColumn needs to be added to the right
    structuredData[visibleData['list1'].dataIndex] = ["cellNewBefore"];
  }
  refreshView();
}
```